# Question about determining the constant for the decay rate of a massless particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

In general, massless particles are not believed to decay for a [variety of reasons](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/why-do-particles-decay/most-particles-decay-yet-some-dont/), but if they were to do so, then according to the work of [Fiore and Modanese](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9508018) they would decay according to the equation

$$\tau=\xi E_0$$

Where $E_0$ is the energy of the massless particle in a reference frame, $\tau$ is the lifetime, and $\xi$ is a constant that "depends on the dynamics of the process".

So, for a single massless particle in space that isn't interacting with any other particles, how would you calculate this constant?

Comment: I think the [usual decay rate formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_decay#Decay_rate) based on Fermi’s Golden Rule would apply. The main task is calculating the decay amplitude from the relevant Feynman diagrams.

Comment: Hmm... good point. Perhaps there is some amplitude or phase space factor that will cancel it, or perhaps I’m wrong that this formula still applies in the limit of $M\to 0$. I have never tried to calculate the decay of a massless particle, only massive ones. Sorry I can’t be of more help.

Comment: The point Mr. Smith is referring to in his second comment is that the usual decay rate formula has a nonzero mass in a denominator, and a zero mass would result in a divide by zero error.

Comment: A relevant paper also written by [Modanese](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9501123.pdf) estimates the graviton lifetime.

Comment: Re-reading the paper, Modanese mentions that the lifetime is proportional to the energy.